# How to hide object between another object with transparent background color

Tags: vector, corel-draw

I have two objects in Corel Draw: rectangle without background color and text (like in this image[image: Text]). How can I make invisible the text´s part which is after the rectangle like this:[image: Text]? (Without setting the rectangles background color, I need it transparent)

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hi MetropolisCZ, welcome to GD.SE! Can you tell us what you have tried? Like have you tried using Path Finder options? https://learn.corel.com/tutorials/coreldraw-shaping-tools/

Comment: @AndrewH - in CorelDraw these are called the Shaping Tools, or in general vector terminology: *boolean operations*.  "Path Finder" is the panel where Adobe puts its boolean operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it works! I tried all of these which you suggested me and right worked the *Simplify* button. Thank you very much for helping, i didnt find the right keywords to find it.